# Does High Ground let creatures that are not able to block, like Skrelv, Defector Mite, block?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander

I am thinking of including [High Ground](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=132145) in my mono-white deck. The deck has a lot of creatures and tokens that cannot block, like [Skrelv, Defector Mite](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=602563) and the tokens created by [White Sun's Twilight](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=602568).

Because of the way these cards are worded:

Skrelv, Defector Mite:

> Skrelv, Defector Mite cannot block

White Sun's Twilight:

> Create X 1/1 colorless Phyrexian Mite artifact creature tokens with toxic 1 and "This creature can't block."

I would assume that this means that High Ground will allow the creatures to block a *second* creature, but since Skrelv and the tokens cannot block, they still could not block *any* creatures. Is this correct?

Second, are there any white or colorless cards that can grant the ability to block to cards like Skrelv and these tokens?

Comment: I don't quite understand the second part of the question, did you mean to ask about cards that allow Skrelv and those tokens to block, or things that allow you to block them? Because they can be blocked like any other creature.

Comment: I was wondering if there are any cards that allow Skrelv to block other creatures.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I would assume that this means that High Ground will allow the creatures to block a *second* creature, but since Skrelv and the tokens cannot block, they still could not block *any* creatures. Is this correct?

Yes:

> 509.1b The defending player checks each creature they control to see whether it’s affected by any restrictions (effects that say a creature can’t block, or that it can’t block unless some condition is met). If any restrictions are being disobeyed, the declaration of blockers is illegal.

Skrelv says "Skrelv, Defector Mite cannot block", not "Skrelv, Defector Mite can block only 0 creatures." so it's definitely a restriction.

> Second, are there any White or Colorless cards that can grant the ability to block to cards like Skrelv and these tokens?

[Humility](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Humility) - the property that creatures can't block is an ability (cf. rule 113.2a), but that card has some *serious* side effects ...

Comment: Humility would definitely let it block, lol. Are there any that allow it to keep its abilities and block, or is that out of the question (in white at least)?

Comment: Not that I know of; it reminds me of [*can't beats can*](https://www.mtgsalvation.com/forums/magic-fundamentals/magic-rulings/758407-can-vs-cant), but the card pool I know is rather old and small ...

Comment: The card pool I know is rather new and small, so I'm in a similar boat lol.

Answer (score 6):

Not white, but [Aetherplasm](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Aetherplasm)'s ability allows you to have a creature blocking that would otherwise be illegal.

> Whenever Aetherplasm blocks a creature, you may return Aetherplasm to its owner’s hand. If you do, you may put a creature card from your hand onto the battlefield blocking that creature.

Unfortunately, I don't think a similar effect exists in white.

Answer (score 2):

No, creatures that cannot block still cannot block with High Ground.

> 509.1b The defending player checks each creature they control to see whether it’s affected by any restrictions (effects that say a creature can’t block, or that it can’t block unless some condition is met). If any restrictions are being disobeyed, the declaration of blockers is illegal.

This is unrelated to the question of *how many* creatures a creature can block. If instead of "can't block", Skrelv, Defector Mite said something like "Skrelv, Defector Mite can block one fewer creature", then such a thing would theoretically work, but that's not an ability that exists on any cards, and relies on the standard English reading of the ability rather than any particular rule.